# transparent materials Issue

Tags: materials, transparency

I've been trying to solve this problem for several days now and have had no luck. I simply can't get an even level of transparency on a material and this applies to all models i've imported and any file type.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/361742235525709825/375628554492313611/unknown.png

I have tried everything I can possibly think of and have discussed this with other users who are at a similar level to me with their use of blender. Nothing seems to fix this issue. Visually you would expect it to be a faces/normals issue, but its not as far as I can tell as flipping them makes no difference,  So here I am hoping that someone with more experience can shed some light on the problem. The issue also transfers over to unity.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/361742235525709825/375639920355573762/unknown.png

I'm using the latest version of blender. If any more information is needed please let me know and I'll provide it. I'm still a bit new to blender so it could be a simple solution that I'm just overlooking, but any help would be appreciated as I need to make a translucent humanoid and I simply can't do that with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I've only looked at the 1st image but you could try ticking the "Backface Culling" box.  It's at the right in your 1st image.  It's in the 'Shading' tab when you press N in the 3D window. - have just checked 2nd image but it's unsure what might be causing those.

Comment: I tried that before and yes it does fix about 99% of the issue (certain angles still show very small areas of overlap when two sides of teh mesh are close to each other.), however backface culling does not seem to be a part of the render chain, just something you turn on and off to check if there are any face/normal problems. In the 2nd image the pattern of the uneven translucensy is the same at the pattern in blender so what ever the issue is in blender its being exported out with it.

Comment: Have you checked for double faces?

Comment: Yes, i used the check faces direction option and theres nothing facing inside  the meshs i can only assume the entire mesh is single sided.

Comment: Are the normals ok? Did you recalculate them?

Comment: when the normals are OK, we can't do much to help you. Maybe you could upload your model?

Comment: Have you got different materials in different parts of the mesh? Is there a vertex colour layer involved?

Comment: I've tried just about everything you can do when it comes to faces and normals. If it was a normals issue im pretty sure i'd be able to see the odd shading artefacts on the textureless model. 

Unfortunately it's not a model specific problem, it happens with any model I import into blender.

As far as I'm aware the meshes use one material each. I'm unsure of what a vertex color layer is or how I would go about adding/editing or removing one.

Comment: With the help of another blender user in a discord group I belong to, we've come to the conclusion this is probably a bug with 2.79. I gave this person a selection of different models, bearing in mind this issue happens with any model I import.They imported in the same manner I do and they have no issues when making materials transparent. They are using 2.77a.